# If statement true then modify several columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to do several actions in dplyr pipe when some statement is true.

For such data:

```
t = tibble(a = 1:3, b = 1:3, c = 1:3, d = 1:3, e = 1:3)
```

I would like to write somehow that if

`a == 2`

then

```
b = b + 2
c = c + 3
d = d + 4
e = e + 5
```

Basically, I do not want to repeat the if condition several times because if it changed I would need to update it in several places which is error-prone.

Comment: Unfortunately dplyr *still* has no good solution for this incredibly common problem. The best seems to be to subset the data, manipulate the sub-table, and then `bind_rows` them back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfc(2:5, ~ {n <- .x ;
               t %>%
                  transmute_at(vars(.x), ~  case_when(a == 2 ~  . + n, TRUE ~ .))}) %>%
   bind_cols(select(t, a), .)
```

If we need different values, then use `map2`

```
map2_dfc(2:5, c(2L, 1000L, 1500L, 2000L), ~ {n <- .x
               val <- .y;
              t %>%
                  transmute_at(vars(.x), ~  case_when(a == 2 ~  . + val, TRUE ~ .))}) %>%
   bind_cols(select(t, a), .)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. This works well for my original question. Do you know how I could assign different text values to several columns when a == 2? Or in this case that b = b + 2, but c = c + 1000 etc.

Comment: Thanks, it works well. I just needed to change integers to doubles (`c(2L, 1000L, 1500L, 2000L)`) because I got an error.

Comment: @PeteK that seems to be a bug, because uptill the `map_dfc` there is no issue and we aere binding a columns to the df column and not rrows